# Porque no puedo poner uno bajo el otro

Tags: html, css

En mi código hay 3 bloques, uno de Instagram, otro de Twitter, y otro de YouTube. Quiero que cuando pongo la página en modo smartphone, se ponga un bloque debajo de otro.

Ya lo aviso a lo mejor el código no está correcto del todo, y estoy aprendiendo, así que quien me pueda ayudar será de gran ayuda...

```css
main{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

main article {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.card-instagram {
  background-color:deeppink;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.card-twitter {
  display: block;
}

.card-youtube{
  display: block;
}

.card-twitter, .card-youtube{
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h1 {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button{
  background: black;
  color:floralwhite;
  border-radius: 65PX;
  width: 260px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}  

.button1{
  background-color: white;
  color: deeppink;
}

main article img{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<main class="page">
  <article class="card card-twitter">
    <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Instagram" />
    <h1>Twitter</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet lorem mauristiam sit amet congue mi ?</p>
    <button>Read more</button>
  </article>
  <article class="card card-instagram">
    <img src="images/insta.png" alt="Instagram" />
    <h1>Instagram</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet lorem mauristiam sit amet congue mi ?</p>
    <button class="button1">Read more</button>
  </article>
  <article class="card card-youtube">
    <img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" />
    <h1>Youtube</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet lorem mauristiam sit amet congue mi ?</p>
    <button>Read more</button>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Podrías eliminar todo el código que no es necesario para entender el problema y quitar ese Lorem Ipsum.Completa el [tour] de bienvenida, aprende qué es un [mcve] y no intentes "engañar al sistema" cuando considera que la pregunta no está bien escrita.

Comment: Muchas gracia, lo tendre en cuenta.

Answer (score 3):

Por defecto un elemento con `display: flex` va a forzar que sus hijos vayan alineádos en la misma fila, independientemente del tamaño del dispositivo. A través de `flex-wrap: wrap` estamos indicando que no queremos que se fuerce de esta manera, ocasionando que los elementos se vayan posicionando debajo a medida que les va faltando espacio para mostrarse.

```
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Añadiendo esa propiedad a tu `<main>` conseguirás lo que necesitas.

```css
main{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

main article {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.card-instagram {
  background-color:deeppink;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.card-twitter {
  display: block;
}

.card-youtube{
  display: block;
}

.card-twitter, .card-youtube{
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h1 {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button{
  background: black;
  color:floralwhite;
  border-radius: 65PX;
  width: 260px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}  

.button1{
  background-color: white;
  color: deeppink;
}

main article img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<main class="page">
  <article class="card card-twitter">
    <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Instagram" />
    <h1>Twitter</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet lorem mauristiam sit amet congue mi ?</p>
    <button>Read more</button>
  </article>
  <article class="card card-instagram">
    <img src="images/insta.png" alt="Instagram" />
    <h1>Instagram</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet lorem mauristiam sit amet congue mi ?</p>
    <button class="button1">Read more</button>
  </article>
  <article class="card card-youtube">
    <img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" />
    <h1>Youtube</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet lorem mauristiam sit amet congue mi ?</p>
    <button>Read more</button>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, muy amable de tu parte. Pero al final arreglé con "flex-direction: column;" Así les obligaba a bajar y luego con "@media only screen and (max-width: 946px) {"AQUI ADENTO VA EL PRIMER MAIN +"flex-direction: column;"}", le hacía que se pusieran en columnas cuando llegaran a las 946px.

Answer (score 0):

usando bootstrap puedes usar algo como esto :

```
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">          
            <p>
                aqui twitter
            </p>
            <p>
                aqui instagram
            </p>
            <p>
                aqui youtube
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se me ha puesto la condicion de no poder manipular el archivo html

Comment: @MusstaaDelyan Eso era un buen dato para darnos en tu pregunta, no crees?? Mejor que dejar que adivinemos qué podemos y qué no podemos hacer.

Comment: @Benito-B el OP no puso `bootstrap` en sus etiquetas, no se sobreentiende que no lo esta usando?

Comment: Creo que se refería más bien a que debería haber dicho en la pregunta que uno de los requisitos era que el HTML no se podía tocar.

Comment: @JuanRivera Bootstrap no es la única manera de manipular el html. Añadir una clase extra a un div también es *manipular el html*. Las preguntas deben ser precisas para poder obtener una respuesta *CONCRETA*

Comment: @Benito-B si pero "El OP no puso boostrap en sus etiquetas", es como si el codigo fuera JS puro y yo le doy la respuesta en jQuery. O mas si el codigo es puro php y yo utilizo Laravel. De todas formas phpMyGuel ya le dio la respuesta esperada

Comment: Al margen de esta respuesta, si el OP necesita una solución en la que el HTML no se puede manipular no está de más que lo especifique para evitar que alguien pierda el tiempo desarrollando una solución que va a ser inservible para el OP.

Comment: @phpMyGuel por algo existen las etiquetas

Comment: @JuanRivera Te estás obcecando me parece... yo en ningún momento he mencionado *bootstrap*, simplemente le indiqué al OP (Si te fijas no mencioné absolutamente nada de la respuesta) que si tiene alguna limitación especial DEBE INDICARLA. En ningún momento le dije nada a Francisco, ni menciono la respuesta que dió!